# Struggling to navigate to child route Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have the following routes defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: AppContentComponentComponent, pathMatch: 'full', children: [
    { path: 'dashboard', outlet: 'siteContent', component: UserDashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'person/edit/:personId', outlet: 'siteContent', component: PeopleEditComponent },
    { path: 'person/add', component: PeopleEditComponent },
    { path: 'person', outlet: 'siteContent', component: PeopleListingComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix' },
    { path: '', component: UserDashboardComponent, outlet: 'siteContent', pathMatch: 'full' },
  ]},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

`Login` component's `router-outlet` is defined in the `AppComponent`, as follow:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Then, the 'dashboard' should be rendered in a different `router-outlet`, with different styling.  This `router-outlet` is defined in the `AppContentComponent`, as follow:

```
<div class="side-menu">
  <app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <router-outlet name="siteContent"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My roblem is, after successfully authenticating the user, I can navigate to the 'dashboard' route, and I can now see my `side nav bar`, that the anonymous user should not be able to see.  The problem I am facing is, I cannot navigate to any of the children routes defined.

I have tried setting the `outlet` property on the routes, and tried different ways of routing, example:

```
<a href="#" routerLink="/person" routerLinkActive="active">People</a>
<a href="#" routerLink="./person" routerLinkActive="active">People</a>
<a href="#" routerLink="../person" routerLinkActive="active">People</a>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try `routerLink` without preceding `/`

Comment: Tried that too, not working

Comment: Try `routerLink="/dashboard/person"`

Answer (score 0):

remove the a tag in "href="#" attribute.

Comment: Well spotted, unfortunately this did not fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

The routerLink attribute is actually an input to a directive (so make sure to add the surrounding square brackets) and is expecting something to dereference like a variable. You can get around the dereferencing bit by adding single quotes around your hardcoded string like: `[routerLink]="'person'"` or `[routerLink]="['person']"`. Or just tie it to a ts file variable and let it dereference like: `[routerLink]="personUrl"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.  Creates the following URL: http://localhost:4200/dashboard/'./person'

Comment: Are you adding the '.' to try to make it a relative navigation?

Comment: Oh nvm, I think I see what you were talking about. Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

it should be for exemple like that :

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard/person" routerLinkActive="active">People</a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: What is the link generated ? and why you use outlet: 'siteContent', try do delete that and also name="siteContent" from router-outlet.  you have to make <router-outlet></router-outlet> inside AppContentComponentComponent (to get the children) and AppComponent (to get other elements)

Comment: You are wrong, if you have more than one <router-outlet>, the secondary router-outlet needs to be named.  I think the term is auxilary routes in angular

Comment: no this is only if you use them in same component i think. i did what you want to do many times without naming <router-outlet>. in your case you will use the first in AppContentComponentComponent and the second in AppComponent

Comment: when you do <a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">link</a> what do you have such result ?